# Migrate data from SQL Compact to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, migration, sql-server

I need to do a one-time migration of data from SQL Server Compact Edition to SQL Server 2008 Express Edition. I'm looking for a tool to do this kind of migration.

I've tried using Import and Export Data in SQL Server, but it doesn't let me import from SQL Server Compact Edition.

Anyone knows of a easy way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Compact is not the same as SQL Server, and stores its data in a different format. What you need to do is export the data from Compact and import it into SQL Server. Luckily, there is a tool on codeplex for this:

http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could do this with SSIS as well.

Really just a data flow from compact to SS.